# Unable to log in as second user

Tags: nvidia, 22.04, multiple-users

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04. Everything works fine as a single user. If I try and log in as another user without logging out the first one, the login prompt just keeps reappearing with no error message. I've tried different combos of single user and second user but same thing happens with all of them.

I'm fine to SSH into the machine as any user at any time, it's just the local graphical login which fails.

Watching /var/log/syslog at the time of failure I think this is the pertinent error:

```
Sep 14 11:01:19 mymachine gnome-shell[562482]: Running GNOME Shell (using mutter 42.2) as a Wayland display server
Sep 14 11:01:19 mymachine gnome-shell[562482]: g_hash_table_destroy: assertion 'hash_table != NULL' failed
Sep 14 11:01:19 mymachine gnome-shell[562482]: Failed to open gpu '/dev/dri/card0': No suitable mode setting backend found
Sep 14 11:01:19 mymachine gnome-shell[562482]: Failed to setup: No GPUs found
```

I think something to do with the GPU. I have a 3090 RTX.

I also spotted this in the syslog. Not sure if related or not.

```
sh[562500]: /bin/sh: 1: initctl: not found
```

Any ideas how to troubleshoot this?

Thanks!

Comment: I too have this problem on 22.04 and Nvidia, using 470 drivers